# Unit test without leaving Xcode

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, sentestingkit

Is it possible to run unit tests without the auto-application-switch to the simulator? It gets quite annoying, especially if you're in fullscreen and you end up thrown a "whole desktop" away from the console.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a small AppleScript that I set to run for *Generates output* in *Testing* behaviour configuration:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
activate application "Xcode"
```

It brings Xcode back immediately after pressing *command* + *U*. I also opened a bug and Apple marked it as a duplicate. So, they're aware.

Comment: Apple should really fix this, but thanks for the fix. This works perfectly.